# how can I bundle multiple libraries with webpack and use them in a browser

Tags: javascript, webpack

Webpack [describes](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/) a multi-main entry feature that seems to do exactly this, it bundles several libs into one file. The problem is that when I load that file only the last library on the list is available.

I've created a small demo [on github](https://github.com/fergald/webpack-multi-debug).

There are 2 libraries each exporting a single symbol, only `lib2.d2` is accessible from the `test.html` that loads the bundled JS. If you look in the bundle file you can see the code from `lib1` but it's not exported in any way that I can find.

The webpack config is below. I suspect the problem is that there's no way to supply 2 library names when there's out only output and so the last one over-writes the earlier ones.

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: ['./js/lib1.js', './js/lib2.js'],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
  },
  output: {
    library: {
      name: 'MyLibrary',
      type: 'umd',
    },
    filename: 'lib.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  "optimization": {
    "minimize": false,
    usedExports: true,
  },
  mode: "development",
};
```

If you're curious why I would want to do this, I'm doing some development on wix.com. The only way to push JS files up to their server is copy/paste one at a time. Bundling a bunch of stuff into one file will save me some pain. My current work-around is to output to multiple files and then cat them all together with something `export const exportLib1 = lib1` for each one. That gives me a JS file that I can import and access each one but there must be an easier way.